# Convert *.txt file

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I would like to Import and Convert a *.txt file which looks like: 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bw-308nJcF01Yl92RURCLUg4VzQ/edit?usp=sharing

and turn it into a Matrix which I can use to make computations which looks like this one:

```
 example = {{"DATE", "KEY", "C1", "C2", "C3"}, 
           {{2013, 04, 01, 00, 00, 1}, 1, Null, 12.23,  Null}, 
           {{2013, 04, 01, 00, 00, 2}, 2, Null, 2,      Null}, 
           {{2013, 04, 01, 00, 00, 3}, 3, Null, 10.2,   Null}}
```

Comment: Is the first problem to Import the file ? Did you already succeed in importing it ?

Comment: @andre The Import itself is not the problem. What makes it difficult for me is that if I use StringSplit[] I loose the empty entries and also the date is separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `Import` the file. Depending on the structure of your `.txt` file you can use the second argument (`"Data"` and `"List"` are useful choices). Remove the parts you don't need (in this case the `------`) and split the resulting strings. An empty list shows up from all the dashed, you can simply remove this using `/. {} -> Sequence[]`.

```
foo = (StringSplit /@ (StringReplace[#, "-" -> ""] & /@ 
       Import["D:\\Downloads\\example.txt", "List"])) /. {} -> 
    Sequence[];
```

Now we build our sublists using `DateList` and `ToExpression`:

```
data = {DateList[{#1 <> "," <> #2, {"Day", "Month", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}}],
     ToExpression@#3, Null, 
     ToExpression@StringReplace[#4, "," -> "."], Null} & @@@ Rest@foo;
```

And finally assemble the result:

```
Prepend[data, First@foo]

(* {{"DATE", "KEY", "C1", "C2", "C3"},
    {{2013, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1.}, 1, Null, 12.23, Null},
    {{2013, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2.}, 2, Null, 2, Null},
    {{2013, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3.}, 3, Null, 10.2, Null}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, import it:

```
q = Import["yourPath/example.txt"]
```

Then you can look to see what it consists of using

```
FullForm[q]
```

where you see it is a big string. So break it apart:

```
StringSplit[q]
```

and you get roughly the desired form.